# How do I configure one menu per area in .Net MVC and other area-specific variables for the layout

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm working on a rather large application in .Net MVC 4, where I have one master menu to navigate through the areas and one submenu to navigate through components of one area.

Obviously this submenu is different per area, and currently I've "solved" this using the Viewbag.

I have one master controller with some abstract methods:

```
public abstract class BaseController: Controller
{
    protected abstract string GetMenu();

    protected override sealed void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    { 
        ViewBag.Menu = GetMenu();
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and every area also has its basecontroller with the following declaration

```
public abstract class Area1Controller: BaseController
{
    protected string GetMenu() 
    {
        return "MenuNameForArea1";
    }
}
```

And in my _Layout, I simply access the menu like this:

```
@{
    var menu = ViewBag.Menu as string;
    if (menu != null)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial(menu);
    }
}
```

The problem now is that there are quite some variables joining the bag of "things that need to be displayed on the _Layout page but are different per area".

So I wonder what the best solution would be to tackle this problem. Do I make a ViewModel for the _Layout page? Do I put that ViewModel in the ViewBag or do I force every viewmodel to inherit from the base viewmodel?

Since every area has its separate _Viewstart, I had thought of using sections to tackle this in a type-safe way, but unfortunately I can't seem to define sections in the _Viewstart.

Suggestions would be very welcome.

Bonus question: What would be a good solution to:

- Show the currently active area in the main menu (configured once per area)
- Show the currently active item in the submenu (configured once per controller but should be overridable to something specific)

Comment: you can use MvcSiteMap for this check this out https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider